# Body contains white spaces after setting margin to 0 (Vanilla HTML And CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a hero image with no white spaces on the sides. For some reason I am still getting them even after inspecting the element and finding out that it was my body's margin, and setting that to 0

```css
.body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navigation {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: light;
}

.navigation-inner {
  background: #eaeae4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation-inner {
  font-size: 28px;
  display: flex;
}

.notification-round {
  background: rgba(240,0,0,.6);
  color: white;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.navigation-link {
  padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.navigation-link:hover {
  background: rgba(50,50,0,.1);
  border-bottom-color: #8acc84;
}

.navigation-link > i {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/*HERO*/

#home {
    background-size:
}

.hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), url("../images/furniture.jpg");
    height: 400px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.hero-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
  }
.hero-text h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bill's Furniture Emporium</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/one_page_website.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- NAV -->
    <div class = "navigation">
        <header class="navigation-shadow">
            <div class = "navigation-inner">
                <a href="#home" class="navigation-link" id="link">HOME</a>
                <a href="#gallery" class="navigation-link" >GALLERY</a>
                <a href="#contact" class="navigation-link" >CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
<!--HOMEPAGE-->
    <div id="home">
        <div class="hero-image">
            <div class="hero-text">
              <h1>Bill's Furniture Emporium</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried inspecting the element and removing the margin and padding yet it didn't work

Comment: have you tried `box-sizing: border-box`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the root also, try to add this:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Read more [here.](https://blog.bitsrc.io/using-the-css-star-selector-to-zero-out-margins-and-paddings-bf4c074b83dc)

Comment: The issue here was that he used `.body` rather than `body. Try to avoid using `*` when you do not need it. body has a higher specificity than * so should be preferred in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using a class selector in your css:

```
.body
```

when you should be using an element selector:

```
body
```

Remove the dot from your css and it should work.